# Boost not finding file

Tags: c++, boost, directory, cygwin, boost-filesystem

I want to use Boost's filesystem functions. I try

```
cout << boost::filesystem::file_size(fname.c_str()) << endl;
```

where `fname="file.txt";` and I get the error

```
boost::filesystem::file_size: No such file or directory
```

I am sure I have the right path because `system("cat file.txt")` works. I checked that the folder is not NFS; it is NTFS.

I am using g++ on cygwin on a Windows 7 machine.

EDIT: I also tried

```
cout << boost::filesystem::file_size(fname);
```

and using `fname="./file.txt"`

In the makefile I'm linking using  `-lboost_system -lboost_filesystem` and also using `-I /usr/local/opt/boost/include -L /usr/local/opt/boost/lib`

UPDATE: I changed it so there is a `using namespace boost::filesystem;` at the beginning of the file and removed `boost::filesystem::"` in front of `file_size()`. Now I have the same error using `fname="file.txt"` but if I use `fname="./file.txt"` I get a new error:

```
boost::filesystem::file_size: Operation not permitted
```

I have tried different kinds of files (.txt, .dat, .cpp)

The tutorial program `tut1.cpp` that comes with it and uses the same syntax works, so I'm thinking it could be a compiling problem. I have tried to find the file (presumably a makefile) compiling tut1.cpp with no luck.

tut1.cpp looks like this:

```
//  filesystem tut1.cpp  ---------------------------------------------------------------//

//  Copyright Beman Dawes 2009

//  Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
//  See http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt

//  Library home page: http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2)
  {
    std::cout << "Usage: tut1 path\n";
    return 1;
  }
  std::cout << argv[1] << " " << file_size(argv[1]) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `fname` a path? Because, then, just drop the `.c_str()` member invocation.

It might be that the accessor functions add some Operating System Specific quoting or escaping. ([example on linux](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d76a37802c4b06da))

You might assign to a std::string so you can observe the value in a debugger.

Comment: Actually I thought of that after; the error persists without the `c_str()`. Maybe you're right and I have to use  debugger